# С++. Перегрузка конструкторов с variadic template

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-функций

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class Test
{
    private:
        std::tuple<Ts...> _tpl;

    public:
        Test() : _tpl{ std::tuple{Ts{}... } } {}  //ctor1
        Test(Ts... ob) : _tpl { std::tuple{ob... } } {} // ctor2
};
int main()
{
    Test<int, float> a; // ctor1 ok
    Test b{10, 2.5};    // ctor2 ok
    //Test<> c{};  // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было создавать объект класса Test с нулевым числом параметров? При этом оба существующих конструктора нужно оставить.

Comment: Добавить нешаблонный класс?

Comment: нет, с этим классом что-то можно сделать, чтобы компилятор смог определиться при выборе конструктора при нулевом числе параметров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
Test() : _tpl{ std::tuple{Ts{}... } } {}  //ctor1
Test(Ts... ob) requires(sizeof...(Ts) > 0) : _tpl { std::tuple{ob... } } {} // ctor2
```

Но лучше вот так:

```
Test() {}
Test(Ts... ob) requires(sizeof...(Ts) > 0) : _tpl(std::move(ob)...) {}
```

---

> И передачу по универсальной ссылке тоже.

Выбирайте. Раз:

```
template <typename ...P>
class Test
{
  private:
    std::tuple<P...> _tpl;

  public:
    template <typename ...Q>
    Test(Q &&... params) : _tpl(std::forward<Q>(params)...) {}
};
template <typename ...P> Test(P &&...) -> Test<std::decay_t<P>...>;
```

Два:

```
template <typename ...P>
class Test
{
  private:
    std::tuple<std::decay_t<P>...> _tpl;

  public:
    Test() {}
    Test(P &&... params) : _tpl(std::forward<P>(params)...) {}
};
template <typename ...P> Test(P &&...) -> Test<P...>;
```

Comment: для  компиляторов версии   < С++20 не подойдет

Comment: Спасибо! Супер! Это то, что нужно. Не знал что requires влияют на выбор. std::move опустил для простоты.

Comment: И передачу по универсальной ссылке тоже. Правильно, наверное, так: Test(Ts && ...ob) requires(sizeof...(Ts) > 0) : _tpl(std::move(ob)...) {}

Comment: Не, так не годится. У вас два варианта: 1. Вы добавляете конструктору свой набор шаблонных параметров: `template <typename ...P> Test(P &&... p) requires(sizeof...(P) > 0) : _tpl(std::forward<P>(p)...) {}`.

Comment: @АлексейЛарин 2. Вы меняете тип поля на `std::tuple<std::decay_t<Ts>...> _tpl;`, в конструкторе втыкаете `forward`: `Test(Ts &&... t) requires(sizeof...(P) > 0) : _tpl(std::forward<Ts>(t)...) {}`, и плюс добавляете deduction guide (снаружи класса): `template <typename ...Ts> Test(Ts &&...) -> Test<Ts...>;`, без которого вывод аргументов для шаблона класса откажется выводить lvalue-ссылку при передаче в конструктор lvalue.

Comment: @АлексейЛарин Кстати, в первом случае конструктор без параметров теряет смысл, и можно убрать его и `requires` на втором конструкторе.

Comment: Такой вариант у меня не компилируется:

Comment: template <typename ...P> Test(P &&... p) : _tpl(std::forward<P>(p)...) {} Или я чего-то не понял :( Имеется в виду, если этот конструктор один. Спотыкается на строке: Test<int, float> a;

Comment: @АлексейЛарин А, это потому что в (1) если `Ts...` не указан явно, он автоматически угадывается как пустой список. Это можно решить таким же deduction guide, какой был предложен для (2).

Comment: Проще, чем три конструктора не получается:

Answer (score 0):

Решение. Дополнительно, учитывает передачу параметров как lvalue. Спасибо HolyBlackCat!
15 минут назад

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class Test
{
    private:
        std::tuple<Ts...> _tpl;

    public:

        Test() {}
        Test(Ts &&...ob) requires(sizeof...(Ts) > 0) : _tpl(std::move(ob)...) {}
        Test(Ts &...ob) requires(sizeof...(Ts) > 0) : _tpl(std::forward<Ts>(ob)...) {}
};
int main()
{
    Test<int, float> a; // ctor1 ok
    Test b{10, 2.5};    // ctor2 ok
    Test c; // ctor1
    int i;
    float f;
    Test d{i, f};    // ctor3 ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Два конструктора в общем случае не прокатят. А если один аргумент lvalue, а второй rvalue? Добавил в ответ варианты, которые пытался объяснить в комментах.

Comment: Вариант "Раз" прекрасен! Один конструктор определяет все случаи конструирования. Спасибо, вопрос исчерпан.